# JsPDF flips image (only safari ios)

Tags: javascript, jspdf

flips the image in the browser safari/ios

```
var doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'portrait', unit: "px"});
doc.addImage(img.src, 'JPEG', 0, 0, format[0], format[1]);
```

how to fix this problem?[image]